# ThreadX Event Flags

Tags: azure-rtos

Is it possible to call the "tx_event_flags_set()" function from an Interrupt Service Routine?

I am referring this link for the ThreadX Event Flags related API's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/threadx/overview-threadx

Under the section ThreadX User Guide --> Chapter 4 Description of ThreadX Services, the API description does not mention whether the API is allowed from an ISR.

But, the section ThreadX SMP User Guide --> Chapter 4 Description of ThreadX Services, the API description clearly mentions that the API is allowed from an ISR.

Can someone clarify, if this API can be called from an ISR for any ARM processor? We are using a dual core ARM A9.

Answer (score 1):

tx_event_flags_set() is allowed from "Initialization, threads, timers, and ISRs". I'm not sure why this didn't get reflected in the markdown version of the user guide, I will make a task to get that fixed.